# rubyzip Zip::FileSystem::ZipFsDir glob method broken?

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

Using version 1.2.0, I am getting strange results when I try to call `glob` on a `ZipFsDir` object.  In a rails console:

```
> require 'zip/filesystem'
 => true 
> file = '/home/me/test.zip'
 => "/home/me/test.zip" 
> zf = Zip::File.open file
 => #<Zip::File:0x0000000880e0c8...
> d = zf.dir
 => #<Zip::FileSystem::ZipFsDir:0x0000000880e028
> d.class
 => Zip::FileSystem::ZipFsDir
> d.glob("*.shp")
NoMethodError: undefined method `glob' for #<Zip::FileSystem::ZipFileNameMapper:0x0000000880e078>
```

Why is it reporting that the method is undefined for `Zip::FileSystem::ZipFileNameMapper`? I called it on a `ZipFsDir` object. The docs clearly list `glob` as a [ZipFsDir instance method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/1.2.0/Zip/FileSystem/ZipFsDir#glob-instance_method).

Answer (score 1):

One reason this is happening is `ZipFileNameMapper` indeed does not implement the `glob` method as can be seen [in it's source](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/3ec40d875d158f73c836a14169d4649bb0a0a84a/lib/zip/filesystem.rb#L549).

According to this statement:

> All access to Zip::File from ZipFsFile and ZipFsDir goes through a ZipFileNameMapper

`ZipFileNameMapper` should implement `glob` which it doesn't so it looks like a possible bug.